# Encoding for FontFactor.getFont()

Tags: java, itext

Hiyas

I'm trying to display this string:

λλλλλλλλλλλλλλλλλλλλλλλλ

which is read from a RTF file, parsed and put into this variable. It is NOT used as constant in the code.

```
    Font pdfFont = FontFactory.getFont(font.getFont().getName(), BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, embed, font.getFont().getSize2D(), style);    
Phrase phrase = new Phrase("λλλλλλλλλλλλλλλλλλλλλλλλ", pdfFont);
        ColumnText.showTextAligned(content[i], alignment, phrase, x, y, rotation);
```

I also tried CP1252 (and basically all the other encodings I found) together with a simple ArialMT.ttf font, but that damn string is never displayed. I can see that the conversion to the byte array inside iText (we use 5.5.0) always returns a null length byte array which explains why the text is not used, but I don't understand why. What encoding would I need to use to make this visible in a PDF?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you tried ArialUni? That font contains a wider selection of glyphs.

Comment: @mkl I just tested, Lambda is known by arial.ttf too. Maybe the cause of the problem is bad coding hygiene. You don't put special characters in your source code; you use the Unicode notation instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that you want to get a result that looks like this:

[image]

That's easy. I first tried the [SunCharacter](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/font-examples/showing-special-characters#1716-suncharacter.java) example from the official documentation. That example was written in answer to the question: [iText : Unable to print mathematical characters like ∈, ∩, ∑, ∫, ∆ √, ∠](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31268867)

I then changed the `TEXT` to:

```
public static final String TEXT = "Always use the Unicode notation for special characters: \u03bb";
```

As you can see, I don't use `λ` in my source code (that's bad practice). Instead I use `\u03bb` which is the Unicode notation of `λ`.

The result looked like this:

[image]

That's not what you want; you want ArialMT. So I changed the `FONT` to:

```
public static final String FONT = "c:/windows/fonts/arial.ttf";
```

This gave me the desired PDF.

This is the full code sample:

```
public class LambdaCharacter {
    public static final String DEST = "results/fonts/lambda_character.pdf";
    public static final String FONT = "c:/windows/fonts/arial.ttf";
    public static final String TEXT = "Always use the Unicode notation for special characters: \u03bb";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        File file = new File(DEST);
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        new LambdaCharacter().createPdf(DEST);
    }

    public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
        document.open();
        BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(FONT, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
        Font f = new Font(bf, 12);
        Paragraph p = new Paragraph(TEXT, f);
        document.add(p);
        document.close();
    }
}
```

I works just fine.

Maybe you aren't really using Arial. Maybe `font.getFont().getName()` doesn't give you the correct name of the font. Or maybe it gives you the correct name of the font, but you forgot to *register* the font. In that case, you will see that Helvetica is used. Helvetica can't render a lambda. You need Arial or Cardo-Regular or Arial Unicode or another font, as long as that font knows how to render a lambda.

If you don't know how to register a font, read:

- [How to load custom font in FontFactory.register in iText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746950) or
- [Creating fonts from *.ttf files using iText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12333018) or
- [Using Fonts in System with iTextSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20534574) or
- [Get list of supported fonts in ITextSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2027808) or
- [Why is my font not applied when I create a PDF document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32618037) or... (there are just too many hits when I search for an answer to that question)

Comment: The real issue here is, that we get RTF text that we parse and then use the RTF strings directly on iText. I guess I need to convert them somehow first, but this gave me a pointer... thanks!

Comment: Nevermind.. when I embed the fonts, it works